# Is possible to have the nodes always expanded in react-dropdown-tree-select

Tags: react-dropdown-tree-select

I would like for the nodes to be always open/expanded without having to click on the plus icon. How do I achieve that? I don't think I have seen any prop in the component that does that. Thank you